# SqlCmd :connect with variables and backslash

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, batch-file, dos, sqlcmd

When using SqlCmd to try and connect to an active server I have discovered that these both work:

```
:connect myServer\myInstanceName -U myLogin -P myPassword

:setvar INSTANCE myInstanceName
:connect $(INSTANCE) -U myLogin -P myPassword
```

This does not:

```
:setvar serv myServer
:setvar inst myInstance
:connect $(serv)\$(inst) -U myLogin -P myPassword
```

It throws this as a syntax error, I suspect because it thinks the back-slash is an escape character.

Doing this doesn't help:

```
:connect '$(serv)\$(inst)' -U myLogin -P myPassword
```

And neither does this:

```
:connect $(serv)\\\\$(inst) -U myLogin -P myPassword
```

And I can't figure out how sqlCmd is supposed to concatenate variables, so I can't pass the whole thing in as a variable. If you try and set a variable like this:

```
 :setvar serv myServer
 :setvar myVariable $(serv)\
```

Then it literally sets myVariable to be "$(serv)\" which isn't a lot of help.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found to this is to set the variables using powershell or DOS scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use something like

```
:setvar serverandinstance server\instance
:connect $(serverandinstance)
```

Comment: No. Because the names for the server and the instance are being set as environment variables, and you can't set a variable value from another variable in sqlcmd. I've solved it temporarily by setting the variable using DOS commands, which works but it's not ideal.